# Can an ATmega or ATtiny device signature be read while running?

Tags: arduino, atmega, linux, attiny, c++

While programming an ATtiny or ATmega, avrdude prints the device signature, in this example it is an ATtiny.

```
avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e910a
```

Can I read this signature on a running device using C++ code (avr-gcc)?  For ATmega1280 there is a chapter 29.6.10 writing about it, but I'm a bit puzzled by how I can code it in C++.

I want to be able to make the device send its device ID back to the controlling PC, so the PC can make decisions on it.

Comment: This question is closely related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/58386/how-can-i-detect-which-arduino-board-or-which-controller-in-software/58388#58388

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use these macros that get defined automatically when you include `<avr/io.h>`:

```
SIGNATURE_0
SIGNATURE_1
SIGNATURE_2
```

For ATmega1280, they're defined as:

```
/* Signature */
#define SIGNATURE_0 0x1E
#define SIGNATURE_1 0x97
#define SIGNATURE_2 0x03
```

in `iom1280.h` (which is automatically included through `<avr/io.h>` when you compile code for the m1280)

For example, this will send the three bytes via UART:

```
uart_putc(SIGNATURE_0)
uart_putc(SIGNATURE_1)
uart_putc(SIGNATURE_2)
```

---

If you truly want to *read* the fuses, you'd need to use  [boot_signature_byte_get](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__boot.html#gaf375d2543ba38dc56697b4f4bc37a717) macro from `<avr/boot.h>`

Comment: I used `boot_signature_byte_get( 0x00 )`, `boot_signature_byte_get( 0x02 )`, `boot_signature_byte_get( 0x04 )`